# Use fscanf to read two lines of integers

Tags: c, gcc, scanf, djgpp

I want to ask something that I write in C.

I use the `fopen()` command to open and read  a text file that contains only two lines. in 
first line is an integer N number, and in the second line is the N integer numbers that the first line says.

Eg.

```
-------------- nubmers.txt --------------
8                                       <-- we want 8 numbers for the 2nd line
16 8 96 46 8 213 5 16                   <-- and we have 8 numbers! :)
```

but I want to take restrictions when the file openend.

the number `N` should be between `1 ≤ Ν ≤ 1.000.000`. If not then show an error message. If the file is ok  then the programm continue to run with another code.

Here is what I done until now:

```
int num;
```

....

```
   fscanf(fp,"%d",&num);                                                    // here goes the fscanf() command
            if(num<1 || num>1000000)                                            // set restrictions to integer 
            {
        printf("The number must be 1<= N <= 1.000.000",strerror(errno));        // error with the integer number
        getchar();                                                              // wait the user press a key
        return 0;                                                               // returning an int of 0, exit the program
            }
            else                                                                // if everything works.....
            {
        printf("work until now");                                               // Everything works until now! :)
        getchar();                                                              // wait the user press a key
        return 0;                                                               // returning an int of 0, exit the program
            }
```

But the problem is that the restriction checks only for the first line number , it's correct though, but don't read the numbers in the second line.

What I mean is that : 
Lets say that I have the number `10` in the first line. 
The code will analyze the number, will check for restrictions and will proceed to the 'else' part

```
else                                                                // if everything works.....
                {
            printf("work until now");                                               // Everything works until now! :)
            getchar();                                                              // wait the user press a key
            return 0;                                                               // returning an int of 0, exit the program
                }
```

..and it will said that everything is working. 
But what if I have `20` numbers in the second line?  -when I need only `10`

Eg.

```
-------------- nubmers.txt --------------
10
16 8 96 46 8 213 5 16 8 9 21 5 69 64 58 10 1 7 3 6
```

So I hoped be as cleared as I could. My question is that I need a code in the program, besides the 1st restriction, that have also another one restriction under the first that will read the second line of the txt file with the numbers and check if there are as many numbers as the first line says!

How do I do that?
If you guys want any other declarations feel free to ask!
Hope I was clear with my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will check the number of integers and report too many or not enough. The integers are not saved except for each one being read into the `value`. Do you want to store each integer?

```
fscanf(fp,"%d",&num); // here goes the fscanf() command                                                                   
if(num<1 || num>1000000) // set restrictions to integer                                                                   
{                         
    printf("The number must be 1<= N <= 1.000.000",strerror(errno)); // error with the integer number                     
    getchar(); // wait the user press a key                                                                               
    return 0; // returning an int of 0, exit the program                                                                  
}                         
else // if everything works.....                                                                                          
{                         
    int i = 0;            
    int value = 0;        
    while ( fscanf ( fp, "%d", &value) == 1) { // read one integer                                                        
        i++; // this loop will continue until EOF or non-integer input                                                    
    }                     
    if ( i > num) {                     
        printf ( "too many integers\n");
    }                     
    if ( i < num) {                       
        printf ( "not enough integers\n");
    }                     
    getchar(); // wait the user press a key                                                                               
    return 0;  // returning an int of 0, exit the program                                                                 
}
```

Comment: Nice !!! O hot code! ;) Works fine. IF you want post another one answer if I wanted to store the each integers!!!

Comment: yes but I will also keep your first answer! Please post another one

Comment: I also want to add an else command to continue the code! Where do I add it?

Answer (score 0):

use a loop that takes the first num and checks is is the number of integers in next line:

int z = num;

```
while(z--){
    if (getchar() == EOF)
        printf("err")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&num);

    // next lines of code (restrictions). Then place the below code before getchar in the else

    int temp[num+1];// space to store num integers to temp and 1 space to check for extra number

    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        if(fscanf(fp,"%d",&temp[i]) != 1)// fscanf will automatically read 2nd line and store them in temp array
        //error ! Less numbers in file !
    }

    if(fscanf(fp,"%d",&temp[num]==1) //if still numbers can be scanned
    //Extra numbers found in line 2
```

Comment: I want also to check for less numbers!

Comment: @GeorgeGkas , Now it checks for less numbers too!